# 'Return' as a function in an array of function pointers

Tags: c, function, return, function-pointers

So here's what I'm working with.

```
{
    int Test;
    void (*functions[5])() = {
        return,
        one,
        two,
        three,
        four
    };

    for (Test = takeInput(5);; Test = takeInput(5)){
        cls();
        Print(L"0)  Abort\n");
        Print(L"1)  One\n");
        Print(L"2)  Two\n");
        Print(L"3)  Three\n");
        Print(L"4)  Four\n");
        Print(L"Enter Selection: ");
        (*functions[Test])();
    }
}
```

That's the gist of what I'm trying to do. This is sort of a menu system for some context (and takeInput(5), will pause for input, stopping the loop until someone inputs a number).

What the problem is, is that using return in that way is apparently wrong. I figured that seeing as how (i thought) return is a function, i can't see why it wouldn't be able to be put into a function pointer array in order to break out of the menu. I suppose I could make a dummy function that basically just returns true when called, and check for that (the problem with that being that all the other functions return void). Even if that worked, I would rather have a solution that is as self contained as the above, non-working example.

Is there a nice, clean, hopefully short way of doing this that is better than anything I've thought of yet?

Comment: `return` is not a function, it is a reserved word.

Comment: I'd replace `return` in your function array with `NULL` and test for the null before executing the function, returning when the function pointer is `NULL`.

Comment: make that an answer and I'd mark it as such. It would probably make sense to check for it regardless to make sure I'm not trying to call a null pointer as a function. My problem was I couldn't see how to leave an index blank (easy now that you said it) of a function so as to be able to skip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd replace `return` in your function array with `NULL` and test for the null before executing the function, returning when the function pointer is `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

`return` is not a function, it has no address and therefore you can't have it in the array of pointers to functions.

Further, `Test` appears uninitialized when you use it the first couple of times:

```
for (Test;
```

and

```
(*functions[Test])();
```

If you want to break out of the `for` loop, you have to use either `break` or `return` or an appropriate condition between the two semicolons in `for(;condition;)`.

A function call will not break the loop. Unless, it's something exotic like `abort()`, `exit()` or `longjmp()`.

Comment: yea, i just realized the lack of initialization.